# Angular Certificate Verification

Tags: angularjs, ssl

I'm new to Angular and I have a slight problem when developing a web application.

Basically, I want to send a GET request to a url, using HTTP**S**.
The server is on the same LAN as me, and does not have a certificate.
When I'm trying to do this, I don't get the data back.

Here is my code, as simple as it gets:

```
...
app.controller('EventsController', ['$http', function(){
    var page = this;
    page.events = []
    $http.get("https://<myIP>/api/eventinfo").success(function(data){
    page.events = data;
    });
});
```

Here is a screenshot of the console:
[Error shown in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqGI0.jpg)

To the point:
Is there a way in Angular to cancel the certificate verification?
Just like python's request option `verify = false`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your question doesn't even make sense.  If you don't have a certificate, then HTTPS ***isn't secure***, and trying to use it doesn't serve any purpose at all.

Comment: see also http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/can-https-server-configured-without-a-server-certificate

Comment: You are right that it's not secure, but it's just for testing on a LAN. I don't need it to be secure, I'm just given this setting, being unable to change that.

Comment: if you don't need it secure, don't use HTTPS.  This isn't an angular issue anyway, this is happening because your PC doesn't have the self-signed-certificate that the server issued to itself available, since it's not a certificate that can be obtained from a Certificate Authority.  You will need to install the server's certificate by hand on each pc running your test application.

Comment: I will install the server's certificate as a last result... I was looking for the option to skip the verification process completely. Thanks for your time though :)

Comment: this isn't happening at the angular level though, it's happening at the browser level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use HTTPS without a certificate. [Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/can-https-server-configured-without-a-server-certificate) are more details about this. I suggest you to use a self-signed certificate in your development environment or, if it's only for testing purpose, use the simple http since you won't need a high security level communication.

Comment: I will look into the self-signed certificate. Thanks for your time. Though I'm still looking for the option as I described.

Comment: @Finkel: Did u find the workaround. I am looking for the same, wanted to test something without doing certificate verification

Comment: @SunilS It was quite a while ago, bit if I remember correctly, I believe I did end up using a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Thanks @finkel. I will try that